# How to skip over a page in history (with react-router/js)

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, react-router

Assume I have the following 3 paths: '/home' '/folder' '/folder/file'.

**When the user visits '/folder/', it automatically redirects him to '/folder/file'.**

However, this breaks the following flow:

1. visits /home
2. visits /folder from /home, now the user is redirected to /folder/file
3. the user presses backspace.

At this point, the user would get stuck in this infinite loop because the previous point in history is /folder which redirects him back to /folder/file.

**My question is: How do I skip over '/folder' in history (when I hit backspace in /folder/file) and go directly to the last page in history that is not /folder.**

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are using history.pushState() to redirect, replace it with history.replaceState()
2. if you are using Redirect, https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect, this will not be a issue